# Access Ninja forms data to display in another form

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I want to display user's submitted data via my Ninja form in another front-end ninja form but I want it to be like:

If I select a user from drop-down, its data should be displayed, If I select another user, its data should be displayed.

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).It is expected that you have ***researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggest:

A form may have multi submissions from multiple users at multiple time.

You want display a submission 
from a specific Ninja Form from a specific user at a specific time,

you should bind a section of ajax to Ninja Form , then fetch data from database

```
$submissions = get_posts(array(
'post_type'=>'nf_sub',
'author' => $from_user_id,
'meta_key' => '_form_id',
'meta_value' => $from_form_id,
));
```

That could be a little tricky. You might need a freelancer If you not familiar with what I said.